# How does Wicket handle cookies, and what options are there for using/not using them?

Tags: java, cookies, web, wicket

I'm using Wicket (6) for an webapplication. I'm a bit curious about Wicket's default cookie-handling. What cookies are set per default? Does some components use cookies per default? What happens if the user doesn't allow cookies, does the jSession in url happens instead? Is there an easy way of turning off all cookies in Wicket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only cookie Wicket uses is the standard jsessionid cookie provided by your container. And even that is optional when working in stateless pages.

It is impossible to say which components use cookies, as there are thousands, tens of thousands components and some of them might use cookies. The only components/behaviors that require a bound session are Ajax components and stateful components/behaviors.

That said, why are you so anxious about removing all cookies? If it is the new EU cookie law, then you can rest assured, cookies for the proper use of your application are permitted. Tracking users across websites that is prohibited without consent, not session cookies or other cookies that keep you logged in.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, - it's the new EU-law i'm thinking about. Quote "" cookies for the proper use of your application are permitted."" - and this is what i wanted to hear:)

Comment: The "EU cookie law" is a bit more involved than that. The UK's implementation of the relevant directive is the Privacy and Electronic Communications (EC Directive) (Amendment) Regulations 2011. A current main requirement of these regulations (as enforced by the relevant UK data protection regulator) is that, to store and use cookies on a browser, a web site needs to obtain a freely- and knowingly-given, specific and informed indication of consent to do this. This requirement may change (as enforced by the relevant UK data protection regulator) as user knowledge of cookies improves.

Comment: So "Is there an easy way of programmatically turning off all cookies in Wicket?", if the need should arise? For the EU cookie law purpose, that is. And that is, forcing the user to use jsession even if they don't have cookies disabled in their browser.

Comment: I cannot answer your Wicket question. But as for the PECRs I mentioned, the regulator accepts that cookies can get stored without permission on a first visit to a web site. They acknowledge that session cookies are less intrusive privacy-wise than persistent cookies, and that in future the required consent could be obtained globally via new web browser functionality. Many UK web sites now mention cookies on a first visit, but most of these still fail to obtain the required consent in the required way. Enforcement will be lax to begin with, so I would not worry unduly about this.

Comment: (Sorry to bump an old thread). There are use-cases in which cookies are disabled regardless of EU directives. That is Safari with wicket content loaded in an iframe. Safari nowadays does not allow an iframe to set/get cookies or html5 localstorage (privacy concerns). So, how do you maintain a session between requests? Wicket needs a way sans cookies. An application I'm integrating with with has "plugins" which are really just loading my site in an iframe...